# Are data tables with more than 2^31 rows supported in R with the data table package yet?

Tags: r, merge, data.table, cross-join, apache-arrow

I am trying to do a cross join (from the original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55111630/efficient-conditional-cross-join-in-data-table)), and I have 500GB of ram.  The problem is that the final `data.table` has more than 2^31 rows, so I get this error:

```
Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.
```

Is there a way to override this?  When I add `by=.EACHI`, I get the error:

```
  'by' or 'keyby' is supplied but not j
```

I know this question is not in ideal reproducible format (my apologies!), but I am not sure that is strictly necessary for an answer.  Maybe I am just missing something or [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) is limited in this way?

I am aware only of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102042/join-results-in-more-than-231-rows-internal-vecseq-reached-physical-limit) from 2013, which seems to suggest `data.table` could not do this back then.

This is the below code that causes the error:

```
  pfill=q[, k:=t+1][q2[, k:=tprm], on=.(k), nomatch=0L,allow.cartesian=TRUE][,k:=NULL]
```

Comment: did you pass in `allow.cartesian=TRUE`? Can you show your code that causes this error?

Comment: hi @wolfsatthedoor, do you really need all the rows from the join? Or can you add in one more joining jey? it is probably a many-to-many join causing the huge allocation required. i think there are some discussions on this in github/rdatatable you might want to check out there

Comment: @chinsoon12 I really do need all the rows unfortunately.   Is data.table just stumped for over any data table with more than 2 billion rows?

Comment: You might need to search the github for discussions as I don’t have access right now

Comment: see https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3957

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As `data.table` seems to be still limited to `2^31` rows, you could as a workaround use [arrow combined with dplyr](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/dataset.html) to overcome this limit:

```
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)

# Create 3 * 2^30 rows feathers
dt <-data.frame(val=rep(1.0,2^30))
write_feather(dt, "test/data1.feather")
write_feather(dt, "test/data2.feather")
write_feather(dt, "test/data3.feather")

# Read the 3 files in a common dataset
dset <- open_dataset('test',format = 'feather')

# Get number of rows
(nrows <- dset %>% summarize(n=n()) %>% collect() %>% pull)
#integer64
#[1] 3221225472

# Check that we're above 2^31 rows
nrows / 2^31
#[1] 1.5
```

Comment: Pretty nice workaround, first time to know the package `arrow`, super! +1!

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding, came to `arrow` from [disk.frame](https://github.com/DiskFrame/disk.frame) : {disk.frame} has been soft-deprecated in favor of {arrow}

Comment: The answer cretes _an object_ with more than 2^31 rows, but that _object_ is not a `data.frame` or `data.table`.  As such, it appears to more or less miss the question.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, this is an anwer to OP's request for a woraround, allowing data manipulation for high number of rows. It might fill a gap between `data.table` rows limit and big data manipulation like [sparklyr](https://spark.rstudio.com/)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to know **Yes** or **No**, I guess we **cannot** have a `data.table` object with more than `2^31` rows if you stick to be within `data.table` only. However, if you jump out of `data.table`, the [answer by @Waldi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72736965/12158757) is a fabulous workaround for this issue.

The explanation below is just an example to somewhat "prove" the ***infeasibility***, which may provide you with some hints, hopefully.

---

Let's think about it in the other way around. Assuming we have a data.table `dt` with more then `2^31` rows, what will happen when indexing the rows? It should be noted that we use integers to index the rows, that means we need to support integers larger than `2^31` in your case. Unfortunately, if you type `?.Machine` in the console, you will see that

> The algorithm is based on Cody's (1988) subroutine MACHAR. As all
> current implementations of R use 32-bit integers and use IEC 60559
> floating-point (double precision) arithmetic, the "integer" and
> "double" related values are the same for almost all R builds.

and

> ***integer.max***  the largest integer which can be represented. Always 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647.

If the assumption is true, then we come to indexing issues, i.e., invalid indexing. Thus the assumption does not hold.

---

## A Simple Test

Given a long vector `v` of length `2^31` (which is larger than `2^31-1`), let's see what will happen if we use it to initialize a data.table:

```
> v <- seq_len(2^31)

> d <- data.table(v)
Error in vapply(X = x, FUN = fun, ..., FUN.VALUE = NA_integer_, USE.NAMES = use.names) : 
  values must be type 'integer',
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'double'
```

As we can see, there is no issue when create a vector of length `2^31`, but we have troubles when initializing a data.table `d`. When we look into the source code of `data.table`, we see there are several places using `length`, which is applicable when the vector is not longer than `2^31-1`

> The default method for length currently returns a non-negative integer
> of length 1, except for vectors of more than 2^{31}-1 elements, when
> it returns a double.
> and we can check that

```
> class(length(v))
[1] "numeric"
```

which means the output is not `integer` as required when calling `data.table`.

Comment: AFAIK `data.table` is written in C++. Do R integer indexing limitations apply to C++?

Comment: @Waldi When looking into the the source code `data.table` (just type `data.table` in the console), we will see that there are some functions like `length` and `nrow`, which might be the limitations for indexing, for example.

Comment: Agree, also relevant : `data.table` is a `data.frame` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233769/practical-limits-of-r-data-frame

Comment: @Waldi thanks, it's a really nice reference

Comment: What is a workaround then?

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor I don’t think there is a workaround

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the argumentation in your answer. R doesn't require an index to be of type integer:  `x <- seq_len(2^32); x[2^32]` (see also: https://github.com/hadley/r-internals/blob/master/vectors.md) Why would data.table need to require it? We can have larger data.tables. The constraint is developer resources.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your feedback. The issue comes from the mechanism of building a data.table object (see the example in my update). The vector `v` is fine, but we cannot use it to create a data.table if its length is more than `2^31-1`.

Comment: That’s nothing that can’t be fixed. It‘s not a fundamental limitation of R.

Comment: @Roland Yes, I agree. It can be fixed but might be a limitation to `data.table` or `data.frame` here.