# Error for cross join / cartesian merge in data table, any solution?

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, data.table, cross-join

I am trying to do a conditional cross join in data table, and I am running into this error:

```
Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.
```

After doing some sleuthing, I still cannot find a solution here.  I have more than 1TB of RAM and memory is not the issue.  Below is a reproducible example, as you scale up `N` eventually the code will give this error.

```
N=10000
J=50
dat=data.table(CJ('t'=1:N,'a'=1:N,'j'=1:5))
dat2 = data.table(CJ('j_prime'=1:J,'t_prime'=1:N))
datfinal = dat[, k:=(t+1)][dat2[, k:=t_prime], on=.(k), nomatch=0L,allow.cartesian=TRUE][,k:=NULL]
```

Comment: Some interesting discussion on this at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610562/merging-data-tables-uses-more-than-10-gb-ram) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102042/join-results-in-more-than-231-rows-internal-vecseq-reached-physical-limit).

Comment: @AdamQuek neither seem to resolve

Comment: The error says `more than 2^31 rows`, which agrees with the expectation of lots of data. While R does support some use of over-`2^31` when indexing, I don't know that `data.frame`s have gotten there yet. Unfortunately, until R supports frames with more than 2^31 rows, you may need to look at subsetting the problem and/or choosing another storage/processing mechanism.

Comment: Any workaround solutions welcome then @r2evans

Comment: Sorry, I already suggested what I could think of given what I know of your data. Anything more than subsetting (splitting the data into smaller chunks) or another storage mechanism (e.g., SQL) will likely require a solution that is specific to the context of the data and the remaining processing you have to do on it.

Comment: @r2evans Started a bounty here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61091313/are-data-tables-with-more-than-231-rows-supported-in-r-with-the-data-table-pack