# data table conditional cross join with two conditions

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table, conditional-statements

I am trying to cross join two data tables, but with two conditions that I need to specify before the join, because if I do not, the memory limit kills it. ([See this annoying feature of data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61091313/are-data-tables-with-more-than-231-rows-supported-in-r-with-the-data-table-pack).)

Here is a *smaller*, reproducible example below:

```
    N=100
    J=50
    dat=data.table(CJ('t'=1:N,'a'=1:N,'j'=1:5))
    dat2 = data.table(CJ('j_prime'=1:J,'t_prime'=1:N))
```

In my real example, `N` is very large.  I want to join so the output is this:

```
    datfinal = dat[, k:=(t+1)][dat2[, k:=t_prime], on=.(k), nomatch=0L,allow.cartesian=TRUE][,k:=NULL]

    datfinal = datfinal[(j<=j_prime & a!=1) | a==1]


> datfinal[(j<=j_prime & a!=1) | a==1]
          t   a j j_prime t_prime
      1:  1   1 1       1       2
      2:  1   1 2       1       2
      3:  1   1 3       1       2
      4:  1   1 4       1       2
      5:  1   1 5       1       2
     ---                         
2376986: 99 100 1      50     100
2376987: 99 100 2      50     100
2376988: 99 100 3      50     100
2376989: 99 100 4      50     100
2376990: 99 100 5      50     100
```

How do I do this more efficiently?   I tried something like the below, but it gives weird results:

```
datfinal = dat[, k:=(t+1)][dat2[, k:=t_prime], on=.(k,j<=j_prime), nomatch=0L,allow.cartesian=TRUE][,k:=NULL]
```

Comment: If you join on `j <= j_prime` (second code block), there is no way to retain the other-half of your first-block conditional, `| a == 1`. Without that, you are discarding those rows too early.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @r2evans, you can't formulate all the restrictions prior to joining. But you could subset data.table `dat` on a==1 and a!=1, join twice with `dat2` and bind together the two resultsets:

```
datfinalA = dat[a==1, k:=(t+1)][dat2[, k:=t_prime], on=.(k), nomatch=0L,allow.cartesian=TRUE, .(t, a, j, j_prime, t_prime)]
datfinalB = dat[a!=1, k:=(t+1)][dat2[, k:=t_prime], on=.(k, j <= j_prime), nomatch=0L, allow.cartesian=TRUE, .(t, a, j, j_prime, t_prime)]

datfinal = rbind(datfinalA, datfinalB)
```