# Why is allow.cartesian required at times when when joining data.tables with duplicate keys?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to understand the logic of J() lookup when there're duplicate keys in a data.table in R.

Here's a little experiment I have tried:

```
library(data.table)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

x <- data.table(keyVar = c("a", "b", "c", "c"),
            value  = c(  1,   2,   3,   4))
setkey(x, keyVar)

y1 <- data.frame(name = c("d", "c", "a"))
x[J(y1$name), ]
## OK

y2 <- data.frame(name = c("d", "c", "a", "b"))
x[J(y2$name), ]
## Error: see below

x2 <- data.table(keyVar = c("a", "b", "c"),
                 value  = c(  1,   2,   3))
setkey(x2, keyVar)
x2[J(y2$name), ]
## OK
```

The error message I am getting is :

```
Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian) NULL else as.integer(max(nrow(x),  :
Join results in 5 rows; more than 4 = max(nrow(x),nrow(i)). Check for duplicate key
values in i, each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's
ok, try including `j` and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so that j runs for each group
to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with 
allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, 
Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.
```

I don't really understand this. I know I should avoid duplicate keys in a lookup function, I just want to gain some insight so I won't make any error in the future.

Thanks a ton for help. This is a great tool.

Comment: `allow.cartesian` was implemented after I did something dumb when I started using data.table: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11610562/1412059

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You don't have to avoid duplicate keys. As long as the result does not get bigger than `max(nrow(x), nrow(i))`, you won't get this error, even if you've duplicates. It is basically a precautionary measure.

When you've duplicate keys, the resulting join can sometimes get much bigger. Since `data.table` knows the total number of rows that'll result from this join early enough, it provides this error message and asks you to use the argument `allow.cartesian=TRUE` if you're really sure.

Here's an (exaggerated) example that illustrates the idea behind this error message:

```
require(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(x=rep(letters[1:2], c(1e2, 1e7)), 
                  y=1L, key="x")
DT2 <- data.table(x=rep("b", 3), key="x")

# not run
# DT1[DT2] ## error

dim(DT1[DT2, allow.cartesian=TRUE])
# [1] 30000000        2
```

The duplicates in `DT2` resulted in 3 times the total number of "a" in `DT1` (=1e7). Imagine if you performed the join with 1e4 values in `DT2`, the results would explode! To avoid this, there's the `allow.cartesian` argument which by default is FALSE.

That being said, I think Matt once mentioned that it maybe possible to just provide the error in case of "large" joins (or joins that results in huge number of rows - which might be set arbitrarily I guess). This, when/if implemented, will make the join properly without this error message in case of joins that don't combinatorially explode.

Comment: Thank you Arun, now it makes sense.

Comment: I did not heed this warning, and ended going from a table with 1e5 entries to a table with 1e10 entries which would have taken 100GB+ of RAM space and crashed my server. Ouch.