# data.table cartesian join warning on legitimate join

Tags: r, join, data.table, cartesian-product

I am sorry in advance for the long post which mixes several questions. If not appropriate, please edit or advise what I should do. I am practicing data.table join, here is an imaginary scenario:

*"Two robots, each has 4 positions in MovementA and 4 positions in MovementB. 
Problem to Solve: for each robot, from MoveA to MoveB, there are 4x4 possible Position-pairs
Find the 4 pairs with the shortest distance"*

**Data Setup**

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(20141220)
dtMoveA = data.table(RobotID = rep(1:2, each=4), Position=sample(1:20, 8))
dtMoveB = data.table(RobotID = rep(1:2, each=4), Position=sample(1:20, 8))

# Review Data
rbind(cbind(Movement="Move-A", dtMoveA), cbind(Movement="Move-B", dtMoveB))

    Movement RobotID Position
 1:   Move-A       1       18
 2:   Move-A       1       20
 3:   Move-A       1       15
 4:   Move-A       1        8
 5:   Move-A       2       13
 6:   Move-A       2        2
 7:   Move-A       2        9
 8:   Move-A       2       12
 9:   Move-B       1       18
10:   Move-B       1       14
11:   Move-B       1       13
12:   Move-B       1       17
13:   Move-B       2        5
14:   Move-B       2       16
15:   Move-B       2       20
16:   Move-B       2        3
```

**Solution 1 (using dplyr)**

```
library(dplyr)

dtMoveA %>%
    inner_join(dtMoveB, by="RobotID") %>%
    mutate(AbsDistance = abs(Position.x - Position.y)) %>%
    group_by(RobotID, Position.x) %>%
    filter(AbsDistance == min(AbsDistance)) %>%
    arrange(RobotID, Position.x)

  RobotID Position.x Position.y AbsDistance
1       1          8         13           5
2       1         15         14           1
3       1         18         18           0
4       1         20         18           2
5       2          2          3           1
6       2          9          5           4
7       2         12         16           4
8       2         13         16           3
```

**(attempt) Solution 2 (using data.table)**

```
setkey(dtMoveA, RobotID)
setkey(dtMoveB, RobotID)

dtMoveA[dtMoveB, .(RobotID, Position, i.Position,
                         AbsDistance = abs(Position - i.Position)), allow.cartesian=TRUE
    ] [, MinDistance := min(AbsDistance), by=list(RobotID, Position)
    ] [ AbsDistance == MinDistance, .(Position, i.Position, AbsDistance), by=RobotID
    ] [ order(RobotID, Position)]

   RobotID Position i.Position AbsDistance
1:       1        8         13           5
2:       1       15         14           1
3:       1       18         18           0
4:       1       20         18           2
5:       2        2          3           1
6:       2        9          5           4
7:       2       12         16           4
8:       2       13         16           3
```

**Question 1** Can you please correct my Solution2 with the good practices from data.table art?

**Question 2** without the parameter `allow.cartesian=TRUE` data.table warns
*"Join results in 32 rows; more than 8 = max(nrow(x),nrow(i)). Check for duplicate key values in i, each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try including `j` and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so that j runs for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE"*

Is it really a cartesian product? Here the join is made only on the common key values, it is just a coincidence in the data which yields a big join results.

**Question 3** dtMoveA and dtMoveB have same column names. datatable join makes the distinction by changing the name to `i.Position`. Is the "i" prefix something hardcoded? And I suppose *i.ColumnName* always applies to Y member in the X[Y] join expression.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You should really start getting into the habit of asking just one question per post. If I'm not mistaken, one of your other posts this week contained about 5 different questions

Comment: These Qs are somewhat related to the same test setup. If i make 3 different posts. I am afraid I need to repeat the context each time. However, I absolutely don't want to ruffle anyone the wrong way. Should I remove Q2, Q3 and make two new posts?

Comment: Richard, let's focus on this post for now. I am enough beaten on the other post. Please forgive me for my past novice mistake and allow me a chance continue learning.

Comment: @Polymerase, not everything is B&W on SO. Here I find the questions quite related for a single post. But of course others might disagree. My advice to you would be to not take comments/suggestions personally. Good luck!

Comment: I apologize if I came off harsh.  That was not my intent.  I'm a bit of a stickler for the guidelines and had good intentions when I wrote that comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question 1:**

Looks great! But the equivalent of *inner join* is to also add `nomatch=0L`. Otherwise you'd also get all the rows from `dtMoveB`. We can't make use of `by=.EACHI` here AFAICT.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23087759/559784) and [the answer linked under this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087358/why-is-allow-cartesian-required-at-times-when-when-joining-data-tables-with-dupl/23087759#comment35288328_23087358) for understanding the purpose of `allow.cartesian = TRUE`.

**Question 2:** From `?data.table` under the entry for `allow.cartesian`:

> `FALSE` prevents joins that would result in more than `max(nrow(x), nrow(i))` rows. This is usually caused by duplicate values in `i`'s join columns, each of which join to the same group in `x` over and over again: *a misspecified join*.
>
> *Usually* this was not intended and the join needs to be changed. **The word 'cartesian' is used loosely in this context.** The traditional cartesian join is (deliberately) difficult to achieve in data.table: where every row in `i` joins to every row in `x` (a `nrow(x) * nrow(i)` row result). **'cartesian' is just meant in a 'large multiplicative' sense.**

Does this answer your question?

**Question 3:**

Yes. Joins are of the form `x[i]`. When `x` and `i` both share a column name and will be in the joined result, those columns have a `i.` prefix added to it. It's the same prefix that also allows you to access `i`'s columns in `j`, where both `x` and `i` share the column name in operations of the form `x[i, j]` or `x[i, j, by=.EACHI]`.

While joining you can change the names to whatever you like though. Here, you could change to `position.x` and `position.y` with:

```
dtMoveA[dtMoveB, .(RobotID, Position.x=Position, Position.y=i.Position,
                 AbsDistance = abs(Position - i.Position)), allow.cartesian=TRUE]
```

HTH

---

PS: If you've any suggestions, feel free to add a FR [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table). Please have a look at [the posting guidelines](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/Contributing.md) before to do so.

Comment: Hi Arun, Your answers are always perfect, thanks again. I am really surprised that I got the DT query OK. As for allow.cartesian, I suspected that it was a precaution to prevent unintentional runaway combinatory explosion. But what threw me off course was the word 'cartesian' b/c I read it litterally. I feel better now, thanks. I thought I made an join syntax error somewhere which triggered a cross join I didn't intend to do. The 'i.' prefix is fine, no rename needed, as long as I know the rule is consistent, I can comply to the default. FR?!? Please give me some years. Still DT baby here.

Comment: :-) sure. Just thought of something. The part `[AbsDistance == MinDistance, .(Position, i.Position, AbsDistance), by=RobotID]` doesn't need grouping. You just need to get the columns.. You can do: `[AbsDistance == MinDistance, .SD, .SDcols=c("Position", "i.Position", "AbsDistance")]`.

Comment: Thanks! that := operator to add a column on a GroupBy is really neat. There is no equivalence in SQL or dplyr. Following your advice the last query could simply be `[AbsDistance == MinDistance]` or `[AbsDistance == MinDistance, .SD]` which also outputs RobotID as info but also includes the redundant MinDistance column. I'm going to try by myself to find out if there is a way to exclude a column, like dplyr's select(dtResult, -MinDistance).

Comment: Exactly. That's why I had to add `.SDcols`. Once again note that using `.SDcols` is slightly more efficient as you don't subset the column you require (only to delete later). You could do: `[AbsDistance == MinDistance, .SD, .SDcols=-c("RobotID")]`...

Comment: Oh this is Greeeaaat, .SDcols = -c("Col1", "Col2") was what I was looking for. This can also be used for excluding columns! I hope the data.table built-in help will be updated to give some examples of that use case. Don't know what other gems still hidden in DataTable but really, there is enough materials to write a book on this topic alone. Hope that you and Matt will write that book one day.

Comment: Ha, thanks for the encouragement. We're now in the process of writing some detailed vignettes. Hopefully we'll be able to get that done first :-). We are (mostly) just two people working on our free time. There are lot of things on the to-do list :-).