# More effective merging of matched column with duplicates in data.table

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I've got two `data.table`s, both of which share one variable; I'm trying to add a variable that's missing from the second, but which is tied one-for-one to the shared variable.

This is clearly a merge, but because the shared variable has multiple instances, I'm having to use what feels like a workaround to merge the new variable.

Let's get specific.

```
x <- data.table(let = rep(letters[1:3], 2:4),
                num = rep(1:3, 2:4), other = rnorm(9))
y <- data.table(let = rep(c("a", "c"), c(10, 6)))

x:
   let num       other
1:   a   1 -0.41695882
2:   a   1 -0.59875888
3:   b   2 -0.19433915
4:   b   2  0.58406046
5:   b   2 -0.33922321
6:   c   3 -0.63076561
7:   c   3  1.06987710
8:   c   3  0.08869372
9:   c   3 -1.31196123

y:
    let
 1:   a
 2:   a
 3:   a
 4:   a
 5:   a
 6:   a
 7:   a
 8:   a
 9:   a
10:   a
11:   c
12:   c
13:   c
14:   c
15:   c
16:   c
```

I just want to add the `num` column to `y`; since `num` is matched 1-1 with `let`, it doesn't really matter that there's duplicates.

Here's an approach that works; I've just got a feeling there's something simpler.

```
setkey(x, let)
setkey(y, let)

y <- x[!duplicated(let), c("let", "num"), with = FALSE][y]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only improvements that I could think of is that

1. You could skip the `setkey(x, let)` part
2. You could also update `y` by reference (rather than creating a copy using `<-` and then assigning back to `y`)

If you are using the current stable version version of `data.table` (v <= 1.9.4) you will have to use `allow.cartesian = TRUE`

```
setkey(y,let)
y[x[!duplicated(let)], num := i.num, allow.cartesian = TRUE][]
```

You could alternatively use `unique` instead of `duplicated` (they both have `data.table` methods)

```
y[unique(x, by = "let"), num := i.num, allow.cartesian = TRUE]
```

Here's another possibility using the new `.EACHI` method, although there's no need for the use of `by=.EACHI` here. I've shown you just to expose this feature for you. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27004002/559784) for a detailed explanation of what this does and when it's useful.

```
y[x, num := unique(i.num), by = .EACHI, allow.cartesian = TRUE]
```

---

**Edit**: (Thanks to @Arun for pointing this out)

We shouldn't need `allow.cartesian` argument here, as there are no duplicates in `i`. In fact, [it's a bug, #742](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/742) that has been fixed in the [current development version (1.9.5)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). So you just need to do:

```
y[x[!duplicated(let)], num := i.num, on = "let"]
# or
y[unique(x, by = "let"), num := i.num, on = "let"]
# or (though not recommended in this specific case)
y[x, num := unique(i.num), by = .EACHI, on = "let"]
```

Comment: Is there any performance difference between `!duplicated()` and `unique()`? I think the latter should also work somehow, but I have no idea if it would be a good option. Nice answer - (+1)

Comment: @docendodiscimus, yes `data.table` has methods for both, (similar to `distinct` in `dplyr`) see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating that! Do you think they'll be the same performance-wise?

Comment: I think that skipping `setkey(x, let)` will improve performance, also the assigning be reference. though I'm not sure how `allow.cartesian = TRUE` performs

Comment: I had a feeling the allow.cartesian option could be invoked somehow, but am unfamiliar with cartesian merges and merge options in general--they're not explained very well in the data.table FAQ.

Also, to be honest, my approach got much simpler as I was writing this question up--was originally taking another 3-4 steps on the way that I realized were extraneous.

Comment: See my edit. Added `.EACHI` option, though not sure about efficiency

Comment: David, no need for `allow.cartesian`. You remove the duplicates in`i`. Your second solution is right on. No need for by=.EACHI either. What'so the advantage here?

Comment: @Arun It doesn't work for me without `allow.cartesian` because there are dupes in `y` too... The `by=.EACHI` one is just in order to familiarize the OP with this option (I said there is no performance gain there in the answer)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, not sure which version you're on. But this has been fixed a while ago. `allow.cartesian` checks for duplicates in `x` (which you remove), but not in `y`. There should be no error.

Comment: @MichaelChirico, have you read about `allow.cartesian` from `?data.table`? In addition, [check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23087759/559784).

Comment: @Arun, I have 1.9.4 at home... Will upgrade and check it again in a few

Comment: @DavidArenburg, right. It's fixed in [1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table).

Comment: @Arun, made the edit, thanks for the comment. I had to downgrade the version a while ago in order to check some stuff and forgot to upgrade back

Comment: With the latest data.table versions the answers only work if you use `y[x[!duplicated(let)], num := i.num, on = "let"]` or `y[unique(x, by = "let"), num := i.num, on = "let"]`.

Comment: @DoubleYou ok, thanks. I have no time to check. If you did already, please edit the answer as you like.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I would use a `merge` like the following, but I am not sure that it is *simpler* than what you have already done.

```
merge(y, unique(x[, c('let','num')]), all.x=TRUE, by='let')
```

Comment: I don't think it is neither simpler or more efficient

Comment: Yes I mention that in my answer, but it is mostly to follow the `merge` approach.

Comment: can't give credence to this given how consistently the merge approach is disparaged in the FAQ and elsewhere by data.table developers...

Comment: @MichaelChirico, the only concern is that `merge.data.table` makes a copy, which might not be always desirable. Other than that, there's no reason. Which FAQ specifically are you referring to? When secondary keys are extended, we'll be able to join even easier, which'll also remove that copy in `merge`.

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf 1.12 is worded against using `merge`; I can't think of where, but I've seen another answer on SE somewhere with similar admonition

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @David, difficult to get much simpler. But below trim a few key strokes away :-)

```
setkey(x,let)
y<-x[!duplicated(let),.(let,num)][y]
```

Comment: never saw this way of subsetting! is there any efficiency loss vs. using the with=F approach?

Comment: It is the same as `list(let, num)`. It will be probably more efficient than `with= FALSE` (though not tested)

Comment: `list(let, num)` is same as `[, c("list", "num"), with=FALSE]`. But the second one is more useful when you've a function; you can pass the columns as a character vector to function argument. It's the SE equivalent of `list(let, num)`, + to provide a data.frame-like syntax.

Comment: KFB, nice solution, but note that this results in an entirely dataset, which we can prevent by doing `y[x, col :=value]`.

Comment: @Arun, Right, especially if dataset is big. Otherwise it may not be a practical hindrance. Admitted, I was thinking of the syntax only. After all we love data.table for its speed, memory efficiency and syntax (who said beauty is skin deep?)! Thanks!!