# Join with non-unique keys, unique in i

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with non-unique keys:

```
> dput(sv)
structure(list(kwd = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c"), pixel = c(1,
2, 1, 2, 2), kpN = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA,
-5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .Names = c("kwd",
"pixel", "kpN"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fc4aa800778>, sorted = "kwd")
> dput(kwd)
structure(list(kwd = c("a", "b", "c", "z"), kwdN = c(3L, 2L,
1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .Names = c("kwd", "kwdN"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fc4aa800778>, sorted = "kwd")
```

why am I getting this error:

```
> sv[kwd,kwdN:=kwdN]
Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs
Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin) NULL else as.integer(max(nrow(x),  :
  Join results in 6 rows; more than 5 = max(nrow(x),nrow(i)). Check for duplicate key values in i, each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try including `j` and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so that j runs for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.
Calls: [ -> [.data.table -> vecseq
```

I expected something like this (note that the keys are :

```
   kwd pixel kpN kwdN
1:   a     1   2    3
2:   a     2   2    3
3:   b     1   2    2
4:   b     2   1    2
5:   c     2   1    1
```

Moreover, I am pretty sure that it worked like that before.

Is this something that changed in `data.table 1.9.4`?

How do I get what I want? (`kwd[sv]` appears to work, is that the new way?)

Comment: Try `sv[kwd, kwdN:=i.kwdN]`

Comment: `allow.cartesian` error shouldn't popup here. This has been fixed in 1.9.5. Check point 8 under bug fixes for 1.9.5 [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md). When `i` has duplicates, then as the error message already says, you should use `allow.cartesian=TRUE`.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say. I agreed this shouldn't happen, and showed you the link that the issue has been fixed since.

Comment: @Arun: I thought you meant that 1.9.5 was already released. I see that this is not the case, it's a development version. When is 1.9.6 expected? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just so this remains answered:

`allow.cartesian` functionality was implemented after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11610562/559784) post from @Roland. Also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23087358/559784) post for additional explanation.

Cases where `allow.cartesian` is not necessary (and therefore should not error) are:

- when `i` has no duplicates [#742](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/742) - this was not checked correctly before. Fixed in 1.9.5 (current development version).
- When `j` has `:=` [#800](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/800) - the number of rows will never exceed `x`. Fixed in 1.9.5 (current development version).
- When the operation is a *not-join* (or *anti-join*), [#698](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/698) - the number of rows will never exceed `x` once again. Fixed in 1.9.4.

In summary, `allow.cartesian` error occurs only where necessary. The fixes that were made in 1.9.5 would become available when 1.9.6 is released on CRAN (should be very soon now).